# getting permission denied error at command line trying to run a C pthread program

Tags: c, unix, command-line, pthreads, command-line-arguments

I am trying to have a program that when run through the command line and given 2 numbers, one for the # of threads and one for the integer to test, to display the sum and factorial product of that int. however when I compile it and run it the command line says permission denied. even though I changed all the permissions to read write and ex. is there something wrong with my code?

I compile using gcc -oterm -lpthread filename.c and then run it using ./a.out 10 5 for example. is this incorrect?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int sum,ms;
void *getSum(void *param);
void *factorial(void *para);

void * getSum(void *id)
{
int x, upper = (int)id;
sum = 0; 
for(x = 1; x <= upper; x++)
    sum  += x;

pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (argc != 3)
{
    printf("Command line arguments missing. Exiting\n");
    exit(-1);
}

int threads = atoi(argv[1]);
int stopValue = atoi(argv[2]);
int sums = 0;
int mults = 1;


pthread_t* tid = (pthread_t*)calloc(threads + 1, sizeof(pthread_t));
int status, num, x;

for(x = 0; x < threads; x++)
{
    if (x % 2 == 0 || x == 0)
        status = pthread_create(&tid[x], NULL, getSum, (void*)(int) x);
    else
        status = pthread_create(&tid[x], NULL, factorial, (void*)(int) x);

    if(status != 0 )
    {
        printf("error creating thread\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

for (x = 0; x < threads; x++)
    pthread_join(tid[x], NULL);

printf("The sum value is %d\n", sums);
printf("The mult value is %d\n", mults);

free(tid);

pthread_exit(NULL);

return 0;
}

void *factorial(void *para)
{
    int i, upper = atoi(para);  
    ms = 1;

    for(i = 2; i <= upper; i++)
    {
            ms = (ms * i);  
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `atoi(para)` isn't going to be happy with `para` being that `(void *)(int)x`, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I compile using gcc -oterm -lpthread filename.c and then run it using ./a.out 10 5 for example. is this incorrect?

Yes, since you specified `-oterm` the compiled executable will be named `term`. So you need to run it with `./term 10 5` instead of `./a.out 10 5`

For compiling code that uses pthread, you should rather use the `-pthread` flag instead of just linking with the pthread library, as well as enable atleast some warnings. So compile it with

```
 gcc -Wall -o term  -pthread filename.c
```

Comment: thank you! that makes sense now, now onto figuring out the seg fault I have now :/